# Creating the following graph?

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm trying to find a formula which creates the following graph:

[image]

Assuming the vertical line is y and horizontal is x, I'd like an asymptote at y = 1, at x = 0 the graph should also be '0'.

Any ideas?

Comment: start with the inverse tangent function, translated it up and pinch it as needed.

Comment: Try [Lagrange interpolation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks very much like the $arctan(x)$ function.

So basically, we want a function that looks like

$ f(x) = A \cdot arctan(B(x-C))-D$, where $A, B, C, D$ are all constants.

Intuitively, $A$ will make the limit at infinity whatever we want. $B$ changes how steep the slope is. $C$ moves the slope around.  $D$ changes the "$y$-position" of the graph (which matters if we want $f(0)=0$).

So we have two conditions to work with, one is that $f(0)=0$, the other being $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=1$

This helps us to eliminate a couple of constants.  I also infer from your picture you want the rising part to be "around $.5$", allowing me to remove one more constant.  So you get the following:

$f(x) = \frac{2}{\pi-2\cdot arctan(\frac{-B}{2})} \cdot (arctan(B(x-\frac{1}{2}))-arctan(\frac{-B}{2}))
$

So, for example, here is a plot of the function with $B = 20$:

[Looks a lot like your graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28%282/%28pi-2%2aarctan%28-10%29%29%29%2a%28arctan%2820x-10%29-arctan%28-10%29%29%29%20from%20x=0%20to%20x=1)

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you see something that rises from a flatline, as your graph does around $x=0$, you should summon $y=e^{-1/x^2}$ (defined to have $y=0$ when $x=0$). It is the ubiquitous example of a smooth, non-analytic function that manages to morph from all-derivatives-are-0 state to monotonically increasing.

In your case, luckily, the function as is indeed has $y=1$ as an asymptote so it's precisely what you're looking for. If you care about the values to the left of $x=0$ you can modify the function by decreeing it to be 0 when $x<0$. Miraculously, it is still perfectly smooth.

This image is of the full, unmodified function:

[image: Graph of $e^{-1/x^2}$ via Google Search.]